# Can somebody explain these lines in this code?

Tags: c, function, exit, explain

In this source-code of Arwin  I saw :

```
fprc_func = GetProcAddress(hmod_libname,argv[2]);

if(fprc_func == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: could find the function in the library!\n");
    exit(-1);
}
printf("%s is located at 0x%08x in %s\n",argv[2],(unsigned int)fprc_func,argv[1]);
```

Why we use `exit(-1)` and not use `exit(1)` here ?

Also please explain the `printf` statement in a understanding way.

Comment: Having a different error code? Any non-zero value means failure, so -1 is a choose for an exit code (wrapper around, most likely 127)

Comment: exit(-1) is to denote that an error occured.

Comment: Reading the manual for `printf()` definitely helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether to use exit(-1) or exit(1) for failure is a personal choice.

[POSIX compliant code](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) uses 1 or `EXIT_FAILURE` for failures

In

```
printf("%s is located at 0x%08x in %s\n",argv[2],(unsigned int)fprc_func,argv[1]);
```

Two strings `argv[2]` & `argv[1]` (as specified by `%s`) and an unsigned hexadecimal integer `fprc_func` (as specified by `0x%08x`) are printed. The `%08` in `0x%08x` is for setting the width to eight. See [printf doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: @piratos - I have done an edit to the question. You may approve it

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s is located at 0x%08x in %s\n",argv[2],(unsigned int)fprc_func,argv[1]);
```

The first `%s` refers to the `argv[2]`.

The `%08x` refers to `fprc_func` in hex with 8 zeroes, where `fprc_func` is a function pointer returned by `GetProcAddress`. The `(unsigned int)` cast the address to unsigned integer (never negative).

The last `%s` refers to `argv[1]`.

More info about printf format can be found here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Let me add an example: assuming you use `%03i`, if the int is 12, it will show 012, if the int is 3, it will show 003.